# How to bound increments of Ito integral?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Given a Brownian motion $\{W_t\}_{t\in[0;T]}$ and a continuous, adapted and square-integrable (bounded if you want) process $\{\sigma_t\}_{t\in[0;T]}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, I want to prove that there is a $\delta > 0$ such that:

For all $s \in [0;T]$ and all $M \in \mathcal F_s$, it is

$$
\mathbb E\bigg( 1_M \max_{s \le t \le (s+\delta) \wedge T} \bigg| \int_s^t \sigma_u \mathrm dW_u \bigg| \bigg)
\le \varepsilon \cdot \mathbb P(M).
$$

For $\sigma \equiv 1$, this is easy because we just consider
$$
\mathbb E\Big(1_M \max_{s \le t \le (s+\delta) \wedge T} |W_t - W_s|\Big)
$$
for which we have a bound due to the distribution of the running maximum of $W$ and the increments of the Brownian motion are independent from the past.

Is there a similar thing for arbitrary Ito integrals (or those satisfying some assumptions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: The question has been edited to ask for something stronger which this answer doesn't give. I'm leaving this here in case it inspires someone else/I work out a way to improve it to give the stronger claim.

---

Since $0 \leq 1_M \leq 1$, we really want to show that we can pick $\delta > 0$ to guarantee that for all $s \in [0,T]$
$$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\max_{s \le t \le (s+\delta) \wedge T} \bigg| \int_s^t \sigma_u \mathrm dW_u \bigg| \bigg] \le \varepsilon.$$

We can do this using an appropriate form of [Doob's Martingale inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality). We have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\bigg[\max_{s \le t \le (s+\delta) \wedge T} \bigg| \int_s^t \sigma_u \mathrm dW_u \bigg| \bigg] \leq& \mathbb{E}\bigg[\max_{s \le t \le (s+\delta) \wedge T} \bigg| \int_s^t \sigma_u \mathrm dW_u \bigg|^2 \bigg]^{\frac12}
\\ \leq& 2\mathbb{E} \bigg[ \bigg(\int_s^{(s+ \delta) \wedge T} \sigma_u dW_u \bigg)^2 \bigg]^{\frac12}
\\ =& 2\mathbb{E} \bigg[ \int_s^{(s+ \delta) \wedge T} \sigma_u^2 du \bigg]^{\frac12}
\end{align}
where the first inequality is just monotonicity of $L^p$-norms on probability spaces, the second is Doob's inequality and the last line then follows by the Ito isometry. It's clear that your assumptions on $\sigma$ let you choose $\delta$ to make this last quantity as small as you like, giving the desired result.

Comment: Thank you! But why is the martingale increment independent from past? For instance, $\sigma|_{[s;T]}$ could be equal to 0 or equal to 1, depending on an event in $\mathcal F_s$. Then the martingale increment would not be independent from $\mathcal F_s$. Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: Whoops, I hadn't read your question carefully enough and had assumed $\sigma$ was deterministic. But this doesn't matter - see my edit.

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry, I also forgot one tiny, but important thing in my original question. :( I want the expectation to be smaller than $\varepsilon \cdot \mathbb P(M)$ instead of just $\varepsilon$, and $\delta$ should not depend on $M$. If $\sigma$ is deterministic, you are right: We just use the independence. Do you also see a way if $\sigma$ is not deterministic?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not clear to me that this method will yield that bound. Of course, one could initially apply Cauchy-Schwarz instead of the bound $0 \leq 1_M \leq 1$ and that would yield a bound of the form $\varepsilon \cdot \mathbb{P}(M)^{\frac12}$. Using Holders inequality and Burkholder-Davis-Gundy, I think it will be possible to improve this to $\varepsilon \cdot \mathbb{P}(M)^{1- \alpha}$ for any $\alpha >0$ but unfortunately I don't see a way to get the $\alpha = 0$ case without independence.

Comment: What if the martingale is Markovian, i.e. $X_t = \int_0^t \sigma(u,X_u) dW_u$? We can then consider $\mathbb E(1_M \mathbb E(\max_{s\le t \le s+\delta} \ldots | \mathcal F_s))$ and replace $\mathcal F_s$ by $X_s$. Can we also apply a modified version of the Doob martingale inequality to not the expectation of the maximum value of the martingale, but to the expectation conditioned on the shifted starting value $X_s$? I have no idea how to modify the Doob's inequality into a version with conditional expectations.

Comment: I think I proved such a version of Doob's inequality. :) It should be true even for non-Markov processes. That is, $\mathbb E(\max_{s\le t \le r} | M_t - M_s |^2 | \mathcal F_s ) \le 4 \mathbb E( (M_r - M_s)^2 | \mathcal F_s)$ for any $L^2$-martingale.

Comment: Sorry, I'd missed your last comment. Isnt that just the usual form of Doobs inequality in the $L^2$ case?

Comment: Sorry, I also missed your last comment. :( The version of Doob's inequality that you used is without conditional expectation.